# Should in encode id in Edit and Update Operation

Tags: spring-mvc

I am making a simple crud operation in Spring and hibernate Project. when i click in edit my Url is **edit/{id}** and for update is **update/{id}**.The id is primary key,auto generated  which was save in database like 1,2,3...
I want to know that id should be encoded or not in html page.Can anyone help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to provide security

1. Encode the id use Base64.
2. Encoded id return to front
3. When click to edit the id will come to controller
4. Then you can easily decode it.

Answer (score 0):

No need to encode the ID.

Its okay to keep it as it is.

If you are afraid of security then apply security on method or application level.